# Why does the right-hand-side of clause not agree with function result type?

Tags: sml

Starting with this data type defined in SML --

```
datatype exp = Constant of int
         | Negate of exp
         | Add of exp * exp
         | Multiply of exp * exp
```

I've written this function which is supposed to list all constants in a given exp:

```
fun lst_con e = 
        case e of
          Constant i => [i]
        | Negate e2 =>  [~ (lst_con e2)]
        | Add(e1, e2) => [(lst_con e1)] @ [(lst_con e2)]
        | Multiply(e1, e2) => [(lst_con e1)] @ [(lst_con e2)]
```

However, it is returning this error:

```
Error: right-hand-side of clause does not agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]    
  expression:  int list    
  result type:  int
```

I don't understand why.  Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at `~ (lst_con e2)` and consider the type of `lst_con e2`.

Comment: Also, if `lst_con e1` is an `int list`, `[lst_con e1]` is an `int list list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As molbdnilo has hinted in comments, `lst_con` is expected to return a list of `int` values: an `int list`.

In your `Negate e2` case, you're trying to negative (with `~`), a entire list. But `op~` expects an `int`, so the types don't work.

You also have your first case returning an `int list` but then the other cases return `int list list`.

Additionally, you may be overthinking this. If you have `Negate (Constant 42)` then negative 42 doesn't exist in that expression as a constant. Only `42` does.

You probably meant to write something more like:

```ml
fun lst_con e = 
  case e of
    Constant i       => [i]
  | Negate e2        => lst_con e2
  | Add(e1, e2)      => lst_con e1 @ lst_con e2
  | Multiply(e1, e2) => lst_con e1 @ lst_con e2;
```

Which we can write more concisely as:

```ml
fun lst_con(Constant i)       => [i]
  | lst_con(Negate e2)        => lst_con e2
  | lst_con(Add(e1, e2))      => lst_con e1 @ lst_con e2
  | lst_con(Multiply(e1, e2)) => lst_con e1 @ lst_con e2;
```

### Efficiency Issues

As an additional note, we can see that this function is not tail-recursive, and the use of list append in this way leads to very poor performance characteristics: O(n^2).

We can achieve this with O(n) runtime performance by using a stack of values left to process and an accumulator.

```ml
fun lst_con'(Constant i, acc, []) = List.rev(i :: acc)
  | lst_con'(Constant i, acc, x::xs) = lst_con'(x, i :: acc, xs)
  | lst_con'(Negate e2, acc, stack) = lst_con'(e2, acc, stack)
  | lst_con'(Add(e1, e2), acc, stack) = lst_con'(e1, acc, e2 :: stack)
  | lst_con'(Multiply(e1, e2), acc, stack) = lst_con'(e1, acc, e2 :: stack);

fun lst_con(e) = lst_con'(e, [], []);
```

If we examine how a test case evaluates:

```
lst_con(Multiply(Add(Negate(Constant 2), Constant 6), Add(Multiply(Constant 1, Constant 1), Constant 7)))

lst_con'(Multiply(Add(Negate(Constant 2), Constant 6), Add(Multiply(Constant 1, Constant 1), Constant 7)), [], [])

lst_con'(Add(Negate(Constant 2), Constant 6), [], [Add(Multiply(Constant 1, Constant 1), Constant 7)])

lst_con'(Negate(Constant 2), [], [Constant 6, Add(Multiply(Constant 1, Constant 1), Constant 7)]

lst_con'(Constant 2, [], [Constant 6, Add(Multiply(Constant 1, Constant 1), Constant 7)]

lst_con'(Constant 6, [2], [Add(Multiply(Constant 1, Constant 1), Constant 7)]

lst_con'(Add(Multiply(Constant 1, Constant 1), Constant 7), [6, 2], []

lst_con'(Multiply(Constant 1, Constant 1), [6, 2], [Constant 7]

lst_con'(Constant 1, [6, 2], [Constant 1, Constant 7]

lst_con'(Constant 1, [1, 6, 2], [Constant 7]

lst_con'(Constant 7, [1, 1, 6, 2], []

List.rev([7, 1, 1, 6, 2])

[2, 6, 1, 1, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! Once molbdnilo supplied the hint, I saw my mistake right away. My revised function looked exactly like what you wrote under "something more like."